# Spring Web - Multipart.transferTo() doesn't save a picture on a computer

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, multipartform-data

I have a function to save pictures from a form to my local machine. I don't use Docker!

```
    public Set<PictureDto> saveOnDisk(MultipartFile[] pictures, AnnouncementDto saved) throws IOException, IllegalArgumentException {
        HashSet<Picture> picturesSet = new HashSet<>();
        if (pictures.length == 0) {
            return Set.of();
        }
        Path imagesPath = Paths.get("../images");
        File folder = imagesPath.toFile();
        if (Files.notExists(imagesPath)) {
            Boolean isWindows = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().contains("win");
            givePermissions(isWindows, imagesPath);
            Files.createDirectory(imagesPath);
        }
        for (MultipartFile picture : pictures) {
            picture.transferTo(folder);
            picturesSet.add(new Picture(null, String.format("%s/%s", "images", picture.getOriginalFilename()), AnnouncementDtoMapper.map(saved)));
        }
        List<Picture> savedPictures = pictureRepository.saveAll(picturesSet);
        return savedPictures.stream().map(PictureDtoMapper::map).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }
```

Suppose that the folder "images" has been already created. Unfortunately, in spite of everything goes okay and no exception is being thrown, pictures aren't saved to "../images" folder which is a sibling of the project folder. Info about pictures is being saved to a database. Using a debugger I've found out that there are Multipart objects from the form.

Earlier, I had to struggle with AccessDeniedException, when I used a Path object as a picture.transferTo() parameter.

This method is also weird due to I use new IO API and old one together.

What should I do to save pictures from the form on my computer?

Comment: Debug or add logging so that you can tell exactly which path is being taken. Which `if` statement, which loops, etc.